# How can I play a regular audio CD and/or DVD with the vlc.py module in python?

Tags: python, vlc

I have been creating a media player for use in my car using python and Tkinter, while using the [vlc python bindings](https://wiki.videolan.org/python_bindings) (vlc.py) for playing music and video. I have figured out how to play mp3s and mp4 files, but I cannot figure out how to play CDs and DVDs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code that works for playing mp3s

```
import vlc
instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
media = instance.media_new('path/to/mp3')
player.set_media(media)
player.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found here on the VideoLAN Forums:
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=136746&p=451666#p451666

To play a single track:

```
import vlc

Player = vlc.MediaPlayer("cdda:///O:/", ":cdda-track=3")
Player.play()

while True:
    pass
```

To play an entire CD:

```
instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
medialist = instance.media_list_new()
listplayer = instance.media_list_player_new()
listplayer.set_media_player(player)
for i in (range(1,10)):          # the second value for range() can be set without problem also higher
    track = instance.media_new("cdda:///O:/", (":cdda-track=" + str(i)))
    medialist.add_media(track)
listplayer.set_media_list(medialist)
listplayer.play()

while True:
    pass
```

where `O:` is the drive letter.

Comment: This will only play tracks 1-10. To play a whole CD, surely you only need to add `cdda:///O:` to the playlist